# Distribution of safe primes generated using different techniques

Tags: prime-numbers, safe-prime

Is there any difference in the distribution of safe primes generated by creating prime $q$ and testing $2q+1$ for primality, compared to generating a larger prime $p$ and testing $(p-1)/2$ instead? The former is what is used in practice for efficiency. For the purposes of this question, I am assuming primality is determined by creating an odd integer, subjecting it to a sufficient number of Miller-Rabin tests, and incrementing it by two if it is composite before testing it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\{p \in \mathbb Z \mid \text{$p$ is prime and $(p - 1)/2$ is prime}\} = \{2q + 1 \in \mathbb Z \mid \text{$q$ is prime and $2q + 1$ is prime}\}$

With your intervals suitably adjusted, the algorithm considers the same candidates with the same probability whether you check $p$ or $q$ for primality first.

Comment: Seems obvious now. I knew this was a silly question. Thanks!

Comment: While this is mathematically true (+1), there is still a minor issue hidden in "intervals suitably adjusted". It is at least conceivable that a given algorithm using a pseudorandom number generator might behave sufficiently different on different intervals so that the generated primes follow a slightly different distribution. Whether or not that would be exploitable (which I highly doubt) is a different question.

Comment: @JohnColeman If there were a way to distinguish that from uniform random, then the mere act of searching for RSA moduli with it would break the pseudorandom generator, so it wouldn't be a very good pseudorandom generator.